# Does a black belt have to tell the police that he/she is a black belt

Tags: united-states, police, disclosure

Someone I knew told me that if a black belt in martial arts is pulled over, he/she has to tell the police that he/she is a black belt because he/she is a deadly weapon.

I told him that I didn't believe him because that sounds way too much like a threat, but he seemed really convinced that it was true.

Is it true?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Hard to *prove* a negative, but the answer is no.  Here's some support:

- https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/q/72
- http://www.fightingarts.com/reading/article.php?id=460 explains possible origins of this myth:

> By Jonathan Maberry
>
> This is one of the oldest American martial arts legends, and there is
>   absolutely no basis or reality in it. First off, there is no
>   department or process within the U.S. government to regulate martial
>   arts, which means there is no instrument in place to identify persons
>   practicing fighting arts, and no governmental method by which
>   practitioners can be evaluated. ... 
>   Actually there is not a country on earth where martial artists are
>   required to register themselves as weapons, deadly or otherwise.
>
> This myth has its roots in two different aspects of mid-20th century
>   history. In post-World War II Japan traditional martial arts were made
>   illegal, and records were kept of those persons who were experienced
>   practitioners of the arts. This was a bit of anti-Japanese backlash
>   following the war and lasted only a few years. It has not been
>   repeated, and it never spread beyond the borders of Japan.
>
> The other root is planted in the soil of the rich and often outrageous
>   history of professional boxing. In the Joe Lewis era (the boxer, not
>   the karate master), it was a common publicity stunt to have police on
>   hand during a press conference to “register” the boxer as a deadly
>   weapon. Understand, this was just a publicity stunt and carried no
>   more legal weight than receiving the Key to the City actually means
>   you can open any door with it and just walk in.
>
> In court cases involving violent confrontations, lawyers and judges
>   may advise the jury to bear in mind a person’s martial arts, boxing,
>   or military combat training when evaluating the facts of the case. For
>   example, in the Matter of the Welfare of D.S.F., 416 N.W.2d 772 (Minn.
>   App. 1988), the Minnesota Court of Appeals concluded that the
>   defendant, who had "substantial experience in karate," was aware
>   enough of the potential of his blows to deliberately break the
>   plaintiff’s jaw. But that is a lot different from legally stating that
>   the person in question is a registered or licensed “deadly weapon”.

Comment: Not exactly.  They can be charged with felony assault, and the prosecutor can argue they were likely to cause grave bodily harm due to their training/expertise, but I defy you to produce a finding in law that bare hands or feet constitute a "deadly weapon," because that is a defined term of art.

Comment: it is also worth considering that one can cause any manner of bodily harm and even death without a weapon, even in the absence of any training or expertise.

Comment: @phoog Indeed.  The FBI keeps [data on the weapons](https://www.fbi.gov/about-us/cjis/ucr/crime-in-the-u.s/2012/crime-in-the-u.s.-2012/offenses-known-to-law-enforcement/expanded-homicide/expanded_homicide_data_table_8_murder_victims_by_weapon_2008-2012.xls) used in US homicides.  The category "Personal weapons" (punching, kicking, pushing, etc.) accounts for more homicides than rifles and shotguns combined.

Comment: @DanHenderson: It is also purely B.S.  I would love to see a form and/or statute from any U.S. government for "registering a deadly weapon."  We don't even have _gun_ registries, except for a few rogue municipalities.

Comment: @feetwet I just did a quick Google search, which supports your position. It must have simply been a requirement from his own instructor or school, as opposed to any binding legal requirement. I did find this additional text of the article quoted above: _What’s truly disturbing, however, is that some martial artists carry “registration cards” they’ve received from their instructors. Those instructors charge them a hefty fee to be registered, and the students believe what they’ve been told—that they’re now listed as deadly weapons._

Comment: @DanHenderson: I also can't imagine a reasonably sane person would have tried more than once to "notify an airline" of one's status as a "deadly weapon."  Or maybe this happens frequently enough that they have a canned response, like, "OK, sir, we'll notify Homeland Security."  Or, "Sir, as you know, the TSA has banned deadly weapons from commercial flights.  Please be sure to remove your hands before passing through security.  You can put them in your checked luggage."

Comment: All seems highly dubious. Do you have to register a baseball bat as a deadly weapon? A lump hammer? A bread knife? A large stone? There are a lot of things that are deadly weapons in the wrong hands, and you don't have to register anywhere to possess them.